# Zend framework and Multi-row forms: How do check the next row exists?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I have a form with a couple of regular inputs and then a section with lots of rows. Each row contains a set of text inputs such as rate, quantity, total etc. The inputs have id and names such as exp_id[0], exp_id[1], rate[0], rate[1], qty[0] etc. It's something along the lines of a spreadsheet.

I'm just making the form in the view file, then when it's submitted I'm creating a Zend_Form in order to use it's validation functionality but I'm not rendering the zend form. When the form (as created in the view file) is submitted I want to loop through the arrays for each input in a row (exp_id[], rate[], qty[], total[] etc) and add an element to the zend form if certain elements in each row are filled, but I'm having trouble looping through the rows with a while loop.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

    $this->formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $expRows = array();

    $counter = 0;
    while (array_key_exists ( $this->formData['exp_id'][$counter], $this->formData['exp_id'])) {

    // get required elements
    $rowElements = array();
    $rowElements[] = $this->view->formData['exp_type_id'][$counter]; 
    $rowElements[] = $this->view->formData['total'][$counter];

    // if required elements are not empty then take note of row number for the zend form       
    if (!in_array ("", $rowElements)) {
        $expRows[] = $counter;
    }

    $counter++;

    $invisibleForm = $this->makeForm("newclaim", $expRows);
```

}

Basically i want the while loop to check if the field exp_id[$counter] exists, check the required fields have values and, if so, just add the $counter value to the $expRows array which will be send off to the makeForm() function.

i have tried altering the while loop as follows (+ a couple of other alternatives I forget now)

```
while (isset ($this->formData['exp_id'][$counter])) {
```

and

```
$array = $this->formData['exp_id']; 
while (array_key_exists ($array[$counter], $array)) {
```

and

```
$array = $this->formData['exp_id']; 
while (array_key_exists ($counter, $array)) {
```

I'm not sure if I'm just missing the correct syntax or if I'm on the wrong track altogether.

Also, I'm new to Zend Framework (using 1.12). Is this a sensible way to approach this kind of form? I was advised to do it this way to simplify the layout of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glad it helped, for the sake of the completion of the question I'll post it as answer,

you should use `foreach` loop instead of `while` loop.

for example from official DOC,

```
    <?php foreach ($this->books as $key => $val): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $this->escape($val['author']) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->escape($val['title']) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Check out ,
[OFFICIAL DOC LINK](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.scripts.html)

and [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html)